Remove popup when opening apps from URL protocol in Chrome
I want to add bookmarks for certain apps, like vscode:// or ms-calculator://. It's sort of annoying to have to manually click the "A website wants to open this application" popup.
Is there any way to change this in settings? Or even better, an extension or setting that allows it only for bookmarks?

Welcome to SuperUser. Please note that asking for specific software (extensions) is off topic on this site. The Help section details why this site has this rule. So you're wanting to open VSCode, Calculator, or other locally installed apps via bookmarks in your browser? Does the prompt have a "remember this choice" option? What research have you done regarding this prior to asking?

@music2myear thanks, I wont ask for extensions, this is what i mean. Youll be able to see the link attempts to open the calculator app if you are on windows. And there is a popup that asks "A website wants to open this application". I want to have a setting in Chrome so it won't display that message and go straight to the app. I've done a bit of research, but asking Google dosen't give me the right answers. It thinks I'm talking about websites opening other windows, not websites opening apps on my computer. (for some reason the link didn't work, just type it in)

So links in a web page/html document that are trying to open local files? No, that should never be allowed without prompting. It is too easy for malilcious actors to abuse that to run, invisibly to you, malware on your computer. Also, that "link" in your comment doesn't render. Please note that you need to make that more clear in your question. Use the EDIT button to improve and clarify your main question.

@music2myear I've already edited my comment to say "(for some reason the link didn't work, just type it in)" if you didn't read that, and it appears that you can't edit a comment twice. Also thanks for the explanation.

You should edit the question, not comments. The question should be as detailed as possible, not 2 sentences and 2 questions. Anyways, this is impossible at this moment.
